# Keyvaluepair value is 0 when reading JSON file

Tags: c#, json.net, restsharp

I'm trying to learn JSON and webrequests in c# and got stuck with this problem:

The keyvaluepair has always the value 0.

JSON ([from this api](https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/history?start_at=2019-10-31&end_at=2020-10-31&symbols=JPY)):

```
  "rates": {
    "2020-08-03": { "JPY": 124.51 },
    "2020-08-25": { "JPY": 125.67 },
    "2019-11-20": { "JPY": 119.96 },
    "2020-04-08": { "JPY": 118.36 }
  },
  "start_at": "2019-10-28",
  "base": "EUR",
  "end_at": "2020-10-28"
}
```

Conversion.cs

```
public partial class ConversionRatesLastYear
{
    [JsonProperty("rates")]
    public Dictionary<string, Rate> Rates { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("start_at")]
    public DateTimeOffset StartAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("base")]
    public string Base { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("end_at")]
    public DateTimeOffset EndAt { get; set; }
}

public partial class Rate
{
    public double Valuta { get; set; }
}
```

my method

```
public void SelectedValuta(string valuta)
    {
        IRestClient restClient = new RestClient();
        DateTime dtLastYear = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1);
        DateTime dtToday = DateTime.Today;

        string lastYear = dtLastYear.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string today = dtToday.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

        Console.WriteLine(lastYear + " " + today);
        IRestRequest request = new RestRequest(url + "history?start_at=" + lastYear + "&end_at=" + today + "&symbols="+valuta, DataFormat.Json);

        var response = restClient.Get<List<ConversionRatesLastYear>>(request);

        foreach (var kvp in response.Data[0].Rates)
        {
            //gives Value = EuroDollarConverterRealtime.Rate
            Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);

            //gives Value = 0
            Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, (double)kvp.Value.Valuta);
        }
}
```

I can see the entire content from the JSON when I do:

```
Console.WriteLinke(response.Content)
```

So the problem isn't getting the information. I can use the "start_at", "base", "end_at" without problem in an another method, but not with "rates". When I do rates I'm only able to get the date and depending if I use kvp.Value I get EuroDollarConverterRealtime.Rate or when I do kvp.Value.Valuta I get 0.

My goal is to get the double value from JPY for each date. I'm fine with it if I'm only able to use the date and the double value from JPY. Note: JPY is an example, this could be every currency except EUR.

Sorry if I'm not able to get every element by it's name, I'm still learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look again at `rates` in the JSON:

```json
"rates": {
  "2020-08-03": { "JPY": 124.51 },
  "2020-08-25": { "JPY": 125.67 },
  "2019-11-20": { "JPY": 119.96 },
  "2020-04-08": { "JPY": 118.36 }
}
```

You've declared that as `Dictionary<string, Rate>`, which is fine - but that means you expect something like this:

```json
{ "JPY": 124.51 }
```

... to be deserialized as a `Rate`. You've got one property, `Valuta`, with no `JsonProperty` attribute, so what do you expect Json.NET to do with the "JPY" property in the JSON?

If you're only ever going to get JPY as the key, you *could* just specify that on `Rate`:

```cs
public partial class Rate
{
    [JsonProperty("JPY")]
    public double Valuta { get; set; }
}
```

... but I suspect it makes more sense to just declare `Rates` as a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>` instead (and remove your `Rate` class entirely).

Comment: Thanks that you are willing to help! I can't set the JsonProperty to "JPY" because it has to be dynamic. Say I want to convert USD, then I don't request the JPY and is the JsonProperty("JPY") unnecessary (correct me if I'm wrong). I tried to use your code, but I have a hard time deserializing it. I get "can not convert 'RestSharp.IRestResponse<System.collections.Generic.List<EuroDollarconverterRealtime.ConversionRatesLastYear>>' to 'string' when I want `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>>(response);`

Comment: @JulesHouben: Your error message talks about types that I certainly haven't mentioned, which makes it hard to help you. But note that I didn't suggest changing your `DeserializeObject` call - I suggested changing the type of your `Rates` property.

Comment: Ah thanks I got it! Thank you so so much for your help! Have a nice day :)